# when i implement third party library in android studio ,android studio show error?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, mobile-application

FAILURE: Build completed with 8 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find androidmads.library.qrgenerator:QRGenerator:1.0.3.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidmads/library/qrgenerator/QRGenerator/1.0.3/QRGenerator-1.0.3.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidmads/library/qrgenerator/QRGenerator/1.0.3/QRGenerator-1.0.3.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidmads/library/qrgenerator/QRGenerator/1.0.3/QRGenerator-1.0.3.pom
> Required by:
> project :app

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure you have a healthy internet connection.**

- Go to File menu and click invalidate Cache.
- Re-open your project and run `flutter clean` command in the terminal from the root of your project.
- Then run `flutter pub get`

If it still doesn't solve your problem, then keep following or commenting on this [issue](https://github.com/androidmads/QRGenerator/issues/29#issue-996333579) on github.